# make a multi-selector that gets The state first then the city . React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
I am having trouble finding a solution  to use this api to make a multi-selector that gets The state first then the city.
this is the API = https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse/counties/:countyName
```

This API prints out JSON DATA like this with a province and county assoicated with each Array

````
"country": "US",
"province": "South Carolina",
"county": "Abbeville",
"updatedAt": "2020-05-07 02:32:28",
"stats": {
"confirmed": 33,
"deaths": 0,
"recovered": 0
},
"coordinates": {
"latitude": "34.22333378",
"longitude": "-82.46170658"
}
},```

How could I make a multi-selector that Selects the province first then out of that province it selects all counties associated with it?
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter first for province, and then map the resuling array of the filter to add the counties to your "results" array.

```
const result =  response.filter(entry => entry.province === "South Carolina").map(entry => entry.county)
```